# Wordpress Development

Tags: php, wordpress

I have one project of blog site to be developed in wordpress. I have no experience how wordpress works, I read Codex documentation, But didn't find the answer of my questions, 
So Project Requirements are ,

1: Post Movie with Thumbnails,Links to Download or Streaming Websites,Genre(Taxonomy),Youtube Movie Trail,

2: User can Like,rate,comment,Add to watch list,Share with friends

3: I have database of more than 3000 Records, I don't want to insert it to the wp_posts Table for some reasons.

4: How to add javascript to Widgets,or Plugin (Maybe it's a stupid Question)

My problem is I don't know what is the write way to do it. There are Two Major things in WP

```
1: Plugin

2: Widgets
```

How can i use them in my project ? From Where Should I start First, I have done with the theme Development, And Some Basic Concepts of wordpress Like, `Action,Filters`. I can create this project easily with the PHP and JS . Don't suggest me any premade wordpress plugin or Widgets, I want to code it myself

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean add javascript to widgets or plugins? You can include javascript by adding it to the Theme of the page.

Most of your development should be on a Theme. A Theme is essentially a collection of different page templates, styling and functions that will be used. Theme can also handle taxonomy and meta data.

Since you have a DB already what you could do is make a page template called "movie" that pulls an ID/Slug and retrieves it from the database to get the relevant information.

Helpful Links:

Taxonomy - http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Queuing Scripts - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

WPDB (Database Class) - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Thanks for Quick Reply David , I want to add Like button to All the posts,When User Like on that button, i want to  execute an ajax Call, How can i bind that Like button with the Each post.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be already some themes ready with the functionalities you want. Did you do a search for stock themes? I've come across a few for video/movies displaying with ratings, social sharing, etc. So your development work would reduce significantly.